# How to plot a partial correlation (using Spearman estimates) in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, correlation

I am running a partial correlation between 2 continuous VARs and I would like to visualise the association using the estimate extracted from:

```
library(ppcor)
pcor.test(Y~X, Z, data, method="spearman")

estimate      p.value statistic  n gp   Method
0.3997551 0.0007318872  3.543037 69  1 spearman
```

To visualise using partial regression plot

```
Y_resid<-resid(lm(Y~Z,data))
X_resid<-resid(lm(X~Z,data))

library(ggplot2)
m<-ggplot(data, aes(x=X_resid, y=Y_resid)) +
geom_point() +
labs(x="X | Z", y = "Y | Z")+
scale_size_manual(values=c(15))+
theme_classic()
m +  geom_smooth(method=lm)
```

[image: Partial Regression Plot]

The

```
geom_smooth(method=lm, formula= y~x)
```

option however, obviously does not correspond to the estimates from the pcor function, which is based on Spearman.

Is there a way to do the XY(resid) plot and fit a line using the estimates from pcor.test?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you were doing Spearman as the investiagation basis, the most natural graphic would be a 50th percentile fit, perhaps with quantile regression. I think there are ggplot versions of quantile regression.

Comment: @42- Thank you for the suggestion. Using m + stat_quantile(quantiles =0.5) fits a line with very similar intercept and slope as geom_smooth(method=lm, formula= y~x). It appears that the residuals are normally distributed. However, I am still keen to use the rho estimate.

Comment: Then you need to say in what way you want to "use the rho estimate".