# How to plot a correlation controlling for a third variable in ggplot2 ? R

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, correlation, covariance

I'm used to `ggpubr` to plot correlations in ggplot2, along with `stats_smooth(method = lm)` but I'm wondering how can I plot a **partial** correlation?

This is what I do for a canonical corr:

```
stat_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = lm, color = "blue", se=F) +

stat_cor(aes(label =paste(label, cut(..p.., 
                                           breaks = c(-Inf, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, Inf),
                                           labels = c("'***'", "'***'", "'**'", "'*'", "'ns'")), 
                                sep = "~")), method="pearson", cor.coef.name = c("r"),
```

but now I have a **partial** correlation, such as:

```
ppcor::

pcor.test(x, y, z, method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"))

pcor.test(data$X1,data$X2,
          data$Z method = "pearson")
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated! I've seen some suggestions here, but not with ggplot2... 
 I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50598009/controlling-for-covariates-in-r-ggplot2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49499271/how-to-plot-a-partial-correlation-using-spearman-estimates-in-r), but I still can't plot it.
Thanks in advance!!!

Obs: All variables are continuos

Comment: does [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57886951/partial-cor-pcor-test-in-ggpairs)?

Comment: @paqmo , hi, thank you! but not quite. I don't want a matrix correlation plot, I'm looking for a scatter plot between X1 and X2 whilst controlling for Z...Any ideas?